# What is the actual data size being transferred over network for a Python empty string?

Tags: python, python-3.x, networking, system

I realized that Python3 creates an object of 49 byes for an empty string:

```
>>> print(sys.getsizeof(''))
49
```

But I assume when we send the encoded data, the length is 0 yet the size is 33:

```
>>> print(sys.getsizeof(''.encode('utf-8')))
33
>>> print(len(''.encode('utf-8')))
0
```

I wonder what is the actual size being transferred in the network, let's say if we use socket.send()?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: When you use `socket.send()` you're not sending the object, you're sending the *contents* of the object. Which as you say are length 0.

Comment: "when we send" it depends how you send it.